# share extension subquery to limit the item types

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, ios8-share-extension

```
SUBQUERY(
extensionItems, 
$extensionItem, 
SUBQUERY(
$extensionItem.attachments, 
$attachment, 
ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
).@count == 1
).@count == 1 
OR 
SUBQUERY(
extensionItems, 
$extensionItem, 
SUBQUERY(
$extensionItem.attachments, 
$attachment, 
ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
).@count &lt;= 10
).@count == 1
OR 
SUBQUERY(
extensionItems, 
$extensionItem, 
SUBQUERY(
$extensionItem.attachments, 
$attachment, 
ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
).@count == 1
).@count == 1
```

I want to support only `images, pdf and url`.

But `share extension` is visible in all types. i.e. videos, contacts etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the line:

```
).@count &lt;= 10
```

It returns `true` for `0`, that means `true` for no match, so your extension will return `true` for every type. Change this line to the following if you want to limit the image count to 10.

```
).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count AND $extensionItem.attachments.@count &lt;= 10"
```